# Which document class has produced the microtype manual

Tags: document-classes, microtype

I really like the look of the [microtype manual](http://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf) but I cannot find the TeX sources for it. Does anyone know how this style was achieved?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The manual is generated from a `.dtx` file, which you can find on your system with `kpsewhich microtype.cls`, or by going to [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype).  It uses the `ltxdoc` class, with a number of customizations, see lines from around 70 to 740 in `microtype.dtx`.